# VB.net - Conversion of string "" to type 'Double' is not valid

Tags: vb.net

Okay I'm having some hard time right now. My code successfully work on my job computer which is running an english version of windows while with my home computer, it doesn't work and it runs a french version of windows.

To be simple,

My home computer can understand my code when I use a comma instead of a point for decimal numbers.

My job computer can understand my code when I use a point instead of a comma for decimal numbers.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim provider As String
Dim dataFile As String
Dim connString As String
Public myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
Public dr1 As OleDbDataReader
Dim latitude1 As Double
Dim longitude1 As Double
Dim str1 As String
Public dr2 As OleDbDataReader
Dim latitude2 As Double
Dim longitude2 As Double
Dim str2 As String

Public Function distance(ByVal lat1 As Double, ByVal lon1 As Double, ByVal lat2 As Double, ByVal lon2 As Double, ByVal unit As Char) As Double
    Dim theta As Double = lon1 - lon2
    Dim dist As Double = Math.Sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.Sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.Cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.Cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.Cos(deg2rad(theta))
    dist = Math.Acos(dist)
    dist = rad2deg(dist)
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515
    If unit = "K" Then
        dist = dist * 1.609344
    ElseIf unit = "N" Then
        dist = dist * 0.8684
    End If
    Return dist
End Function

Private Function deg2rad(ByVal deg As Double) As Double
    Return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0)
End Function

Private Function rad2deg(ByVal rad As Double) As Double
    Return rad / Math.PI * 180.0
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    myConnection.Open()

    str1 = "SELECT * FROM airport WHERE (ICAO = '" & TextBox1.Text & "')"
    Dim cmd1 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str1, myConnection)
    dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader

    While dr1.Read()
        latitude1 = dr1("LAT").ToString()
        longitude1 = dr1("LONG").ToString()
    End While

    str2 = "SELECT * FROM airport WHERE (ICAO = '" & TextBox2.Text & "')"
    Dim cmd2 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str2, myConnection)
    dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader

    While dr2.Read()
        latitude2 = dr2("LAT").ToString()
        longitude2 = dr2("LONG").ToString()
    End While
    myConnection.Close()


    Label3.Text = Math.Round(distance(latitude1, longitude1, latitude2, longitude2, "N"), 2) & " NM"
    Label3.Left = (Label3.Parent.Width / 2) - (Label3.Width / 2)


End Sub
```

I want my code to be able to read decimal numbers like this "48.0532989502" on every windows computer.
I don't want any comma to be readable as the "decimal point".

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Always use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Comment: `I don't want any comma to be readable as the "decimal point"`  Thats not really up to you - if the system culture calls for it, it will use it.  You really ought not create class level connections and readers - create, use and dispose of them as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should retrieve your data using the proper reader getter, such as:

```
While dr1.Read()
    ' No String -> Double conversion needed
    latitude1 = reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("LAT")) 
    longitude1 = reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("LONG"))
End While
```